# Why does iReport keep adding tags that aren't supported and then crashing?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

First, iReport is the worst reporting tool I've ever used.

Now to my question..... iReport keeps adding tags it doesn't support, which causes a bunch of errors.

tag

```
<band splitType="Stretch" />
```

Can some please tell me how to turn this auto coding off it's really driving me up the wall.  It keeps screwing up my code.
Oh I'm using 3.5.2 and don't tell me to upgrade because I can't because of the version of jasper server.

Comment: +1 for `worst reporting tool`. Man it is pain to work. When I run it on the iReport it works then after integrating with the code it throws Image, text exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem as well, but I changed the version I used back to 3.5.0 to match the version of jasper report server as well.

EDIT: In fact this is a known problem. The splitType functionality was introduced in 3.5.2, and this is incompatible with 3.5.0. You can see this in [the Jasper server forums](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=112&forumid=102&topicid=62989).

So your options are to use iReport 3.5.0 or to upgrade the jar jasperreports-3.5.0.jar to jasperreports-3.5.2.jar on the Tomcat server.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a newer version of IReport and set the compatibility to the version you use on the Jasper Server.
(Options/IReport/Compatibility)

Comment: Yea if that worked correctly.... setting the compatibility option is causing the issue

Comment: works fine here... what settings are you using and which incompatible tag is added?